# how to use json.parse() for treating the value of a key in json as object not as string?

Tags: javascript

I have a json file, `config.json`

```
{
   "params" : {
        "RegionId" : "${Region}"
    }
}
```

and the following javascript code,

```
var Region = 'xyz'
var Config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.json', 'utf-8'))
var params = Config.params
console.log(eval("`" + params.RegionId + "`"))
```

Now the *Output* I am getting is `xyz`. How to get the same result by not using eval() here?

Comment: Is there any special use case for which the Region variable name is being kept in the config.json considering you are using the `var Region` in the code itself

Comment: Actually, the Region variable that I have used in code is coming as the response of an API. So that is a list of Regions. I want to use those regions one by one to hit some another API. So I had mentioned that in the Params in Config.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to create an object for the variables you want to reference by that json value.

```
var variableObj = {
  'Region': 'xyz',
  //...additional variables
};
var Config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.json', 'utf-8'));
var params = Config.params;
console.log(variableObj[params.RegionId]);
```